# Python variable gives me the name of the user then changes to all its info

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a Discord bot in Python, and I'm trying to get a user name by his ID. So this is what I have:

```
ok = ctx.message.guild.get_member(313628621841498114) 
print(ok) #prints Thomsd#4688
```

This is indeed what I'm trying to get. However, when I do

```
dict_temp = {"membres":ok}
print(dict_temp)
```

I get:

```
{'membres': <Member id=313628621841498114 name='Thomsd' discriminator='4688' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=968274297200197692 name='LE machin de la RATP' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=9>>}
```

Is there any reason why it appears and does anyone know how I can fix it to add to the dictionary the first result? Thanks

Comment: Printing an object uses its `__str__()` representation.  The `Member` class, apparently, has defined `__str__()` to be the name plus the descriminator.

Comment: It appears because you're getting the object, not the string representation, if you're storing it in a dictionary, chances are you still need the object until you're ready to print

Comment: I suspect that `dict` calls `repr()` on its elements like `list` does. If so, `print([ok])` should produce a similar result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `print()` function calls `str(pl)` to get the string to print. The `discord.Member` class has a `__str__()` method that returns `name#discriminator`, so that's what is printed.

When you print the dictionary, it calls `str(dict_temp)`. The `__str()__` method of dictionaries calls `repr()` on the values in the dictionary. The default `__repr__()` method of classes returns a string as you show, with the class name followed by all the attributes. `discord.Member()` hasn't overridden this to return something more succinct.

`list.__repr__()` is similar. You'd see the same thing if you did `print([ok])`